# How to determine if a password was changed remotely or on a local PC

Tags: windows, security, windows-10

There is a Windows 10 Enterprise PC that's password was changed (local admin). The user reported that they do not have the admin password. The event viewer specifies a time and date where it appears that the password was changed while the user was logged into the PC.

1. Could the password be changed remotely on his PC?
2. If this local admin password was changed from group policy, would it still indicate that the user changed it? How would the event viewer record events that are performed via Group Policy or scheduled tasks?
3. Could software be installed remotely with tools like psexec? If it is installed, how would that be reported in event viewer?
4. Could log files be wiped remotely as the user (from another person who is an admin)?

Ultimately I don't want this employee getting fired for information that is incorrect and as a security researcher, I am trying to determine if there could be any additional factors that could give this employee "benefit of doubt" and find a way that this breach was performed without his knowledge or his explicit action.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Group Policy influences password policy but can't change the actual password. 3. Yes. 4. Yes. - Why would this employee be in danger of being fired over a password change? That's pretty draconian and smacks of a toxic workplace.

Comment: He would be fired for violation of the IT Security policy. Aside from saying "YES", can you provide a link or some documentation that I can print? @joeqwerty

Comment: If this machine was connected to an Active Directory domain, the password could indeed be changed, by another administrator.  You are a security researcher, you should be able to find this information yourself, unless of course you are contributing to a toxic work environment or are not actually a security researcher like you indicated in your SuperUser question.